# status code 12004 while doing a service call

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

I am doing a service call in my javascript which return xml data using xmlHttpRequest.My service call is working in chrome and firefox perfectly and getting the data(it is a https call).But when i try the same with IE11 it is giving status code 12004 .I tried searching it on google i found only one answer saying it means ERROR_INTERNET_INTERNAL_ERROR.

I tried opening fiddler to see the request but when i open up fiddler service call is working fine,but when i close fiddler it is showing same error code.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the details of the actual version of your IE11 and Windows?

Answer (score 1):

From the WinINET constant ERROR_INTERNET_INTERNAL_ERROR it appears that the issue is related to the WinINET API which I assume is being used by IE to enable itself to interact with HTTP protocols (including HTTPS) to access Internet resources

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385465(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630(v=vs.85).aspx

If you really wanted to go deeper and understand the issue, try to download STRACE which is socket/SSL tracer designed to generate LOG for Internet Explorer:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7643

On a quicker check, you might want to see if your Windows updates is up-to-date to make sure your wininet.dll is the latest and greatest